# Зелёный слишком похож на обычный

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Зелёная иконка слишком мало отличается по цвету от остальных:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: В самый раз. Ещё бы красную жирную точку сделать бледнее...

Comment: Согласен! Цвет темноват, вот `--green-500` или `--green-400` в самый раз!